# Black externals screens on MacBook 2012

Tags: display, thunderbolt, hdmi

Good day everyone, I could really use some help.

I’ve been using a J5 create for my external monitors to work and all was fine.

I decided I wanted to hook up 3 screens to my MacBook.  I bring my MacBook back and forth from my office.  At my office I have a different J5 create with all HDMI hook ports and it works fine there.

Well maybe I havent’ checked after I tried this:  I went to Best Buy and purchased a different J5 create a “USB-C docking station." I downloaded the driver and spent hours last night trying to get it to work.

I trashed that driver and decided to go back to my other J5 and just used 2 monitors.  I uploaded the driver for that and now I just have black screens, it seems that they have signal “maybe” I see some slight evidence of that but IDK.

I go to my display settings and it allows me to arrange the screens but doesn’t show anything on my external monitors except for a “black”.

I did hook up just to try a monitor with the thunderbolt port, I do get one external [monitor] to work but not the J5 create with multiple ports and I use the USB port to hook up and it worked before.

I can't figure out how to get to [Display Settings] in my MacBook.  I’ve tried the display in setting, went to system pref area and looked all over, About This Mac, etc. But no luck.

Please help.....thank you so much ahead of time.  Sorry for the long explanation and confusing at that...  Jeff

Comment: Welcome on AskDifferent. Please have a look at the tour: https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour. It would be great if you could edit your post to be more structured and concise, since this is kind of a wall of text. Also, give us the exact model of USB hub/dock, j5create looks to me like the whole company. Further, we'd need the macOS version. For now I suggest narrowing down the issue. Unplug all devices, reset NVRAM/PRAM and SMC and start in safe-mode/Single user mode. Then check if the monitors work fine. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255

Comment: I tried to edit your post but there is too much I don't know: What do you mean by "upload the driver". The fact that you can arrange the screens in macOS settings shows that they are connected and the signal they receive is `black`. Sounds to me like a HUB/cabling problem. The first sentences in your last paragraph are really confusing. Also, tell us *exactly* what you have done so far. *Everything* or *all over the place* doesn't help us in determining what you have *actually* done so far and what we should and shouldn't suggest. Thats why I am also suggesting a reboot

Comment: Steve thanks for attempting to read my mess.  Let’s see if you can help me here:

MacBook Mid 2012 13” 16GB. Graphics 4000 1536MB

I went back to my office and picked up my J5 create usb c to 4 hdmi ports and it worked fine yesterday until I tried to hook up a universal docking station J5 create that I couldn’t get to work. So I just hooked up the 4 HDMI J5 create and It shows the 3 extra monitors in displays but the screens are dark,  I have the usb c to a USB adapter to my computer and has always worked.   Seems like something small just wont’ turn screen on fully? Please help Steve tks

Comment: Steve another note is that if I hook one monitor to the thunderbolt jack the external screen works????  I never used that port before until yesterday I had a hdmi adapter to thunderbolt and plugged it in and that was it. Pulled it back out and still trying with the regular USB port and the J5 4 port HDMI...  this has put me way behind with work so hope you can help.  I should of just stuck with the 2 monitors and not messed with it.  Jeff